# Autodesk Forge Dataviz NPM Packages - Trying to use React Viewer

Tags: reactjs, autodesk-forge

I've been trying to develop with the new Forge Dataviz NPM packages for a while but I've been facing errors. I'm currently just trying to load a Viewer (https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/dataviz/v1/reference/UI/Viewer/) but I think I'm doing something wrong. Still don't know what.

This is my React const :

```
const TestAutodesk= () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Viewer
      env="AutodeskProduction"
        docUrn="URN STRING"
        getToken={async () => await fetch("https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/authenticate",requestOptions)
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => data.access_token)}
      ></Viewer>
    </div>
  );
};
```

These are the requestOptions:

```
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
var urlencoded = new URLSearchParams();
urlencoded.append("client_id", "ID");
urlencoded.append("client_secret", "SECRET");
urlencoded.append("grant_type", "client_credentials");

var requestOptions = {
  method: "POST",
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: urlencoded,
  redirect: "follow",
};
```

The final app is not going to use this as the auth, I'm going use a safe backend endpoint, this is just for trying to get the viewer loaded and the front end done. This is the error I get on the console:

[image: Errors Image]

I think the error is that is calling localhost:8080 but it should call an autodesk endpoint. Any idea on this? The Api reference / Dataviz example doesnt say anything about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<Viewer>` React component is pretty simple (https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-dataviz-iot-react-components/blob/main/client/components/Viewer.jsx), and shouldn't itself make any requests to localhost. Are you perhaps making those requests somewhere else in your application?

Regarding the `getToken` implementation, I'd suggest two things:

- It's not a good practice to make these requests directly from the client-side code. This way, someone could potentially steal your Forge client ID and client secret. A better approach is to implement a custom endpoint in your own backend that generates the token with limited privileges, hiding the credentials from the client.
- If you need to make the raw request to https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/authenticate, note that it requires 4 (not 3) parameters: `client_id`, `client_secret`, `grant_type`, and `scopes`.

Comment: Yes, I'm going to create a custom endpoint for AUTH, safe. I was just making the call like that because I was just trying the viewer. I tried to make request to localhost in another file made as a function, but didn't work. I tried to just pass the function to the viewer component as a callback as well but couldn't make it to work. And in the API Ref ( https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/reference/http/authenticate-POST/ ) it says that scopes are not required. I will try to add scopes but I don't think that's my problem. I'm kinda new to react to be honest...